When exactly does static friction work?
We know that static friction works to stop any relative motion between two surfaces. In my physics textbook, the examples that were given were mostly as if "I am giving $F$ amount of force to a block and if the amount is less than the limiting static friction, the ground will give $F$ amount of static friction to stop relative motion between the surface and the block". But I was recently solving a problem involving static equilibrium of a ladder like this below :

A ladder is placed on a smooth wall over a rough surface of weight W, normal forces and frictions are acting on it (I forgot to draw the weight in the FBD)
In this problem, static friction $f$ is working without any initial $F$ force. I am wondering how static friction works in this case and how limiting static friction $f_s = \mu_s R$.
To summmerise,
(1) When will static friction work?
(2) In which direction will it work?
(3) What does the limiting static friction implies in these cases?
Also, I believe the centripetal acceleration problem of a cyclist bending for a turn is also the same concept? In that case, static friction is working to stop relative motion so that the cycle doesn't slip but there is no initial force $F$?

"static friction f is working without any initial F force" There is gravity.

There are two vertical forces acting on the ladder - the normal force $N_2$ and its weight $W$ (note that we are told the wall is smooth so there is no friction between the ladder and the wall). However, without friction between the ladder and the ground, there would be an unbalanced horizontal force $N_1$ acting on the ladder. This would move the centre of mass of the ladder to the right, and so the foot of the ladder would move to the right. Friction between the ladder and the ground acts to counteract this relative motion between the ladder and the ground. So friction $f$ on the foot of the ladder acts towards the left. If the ladder is in equilibrium we must have $f = N_1$ and $W = N_2$. But we must also have $f \le \mu N_2$, so substituting for $f$ and for $N_2$ we have $N_1 \le \mu W$.
This gives us one expression linking $N_1$ and $W$. To find a second expression we can take moments about the foot of the ladder. Both $N_2$ and $f$ act through the foot of the ladder, so they can be ignored when taking moments about the foot of the ladder, which gives a second expression linking $N_1$ and $W$.
The case of a cyclist turning a corner is slightly different since the cyclist is not in equilibrium. Instead, the friction between the cycles tyres and the ground now supplies the centripetal force that is required to bend the cyclist's path - there is no opposing horizontal force acting on the cyclist because this is not an equilibrium situation.
As the example of the cyclist shows, it is a mistake to think that friction must always act in opposition to an imposed force.

Thanks a lot for your answer. "As the example of the cyclist shows, it is a mistake to think that friction must always act in opposition to an imposed force" so my question was : when does static friction work then?

@akifsami Static friction acts in any situation where there would be relative motion between two surfaces without it. In the case of the cyclist static friction acts because without it the bikes tyres would slide across the ground.

Thanks man. Got it

When you look at a concept like static friction you can visualize it as in the case that say you stand at a vantage point to clearly see the ladder in the say, $xy$ plane so what you can see here is that the weight acting downwards at the midpoint of the ladder (considering uniform density distribution and mass distribution stuff like that) so the ladder is currently in that state of what you can say, at rest so the best analogy to draw out here is that, yes static friction is applicable on bodies at rest, basically understand it like this,
Imagine your question's scenario and you standing there observing it (as an observer) so, there are a couple of things to look at here,

Yes, there is no force at all acting to put the ladder 'in motion'
There is no relative motion between the ground and the ladder's end

Now focus on the second option,
If you know vectors, you can imagine the lower end now for the sake of simplicity, translate the problem to a simpler scenario, say a block, on the ground at rest, not moving to make it move, you will have to apply force to it, now lets say you applied force '$F$' to it and as a consequence the ground opposed with a frictional force '$f$' you are now trying your best to put this into motion but you fail so you add a force '$F'$' such that $F'>F$ and lo and behold the block moves, so lets dissect the situation
You add force in this direction and get a frictional force in opposite direction

The block is having a force of friction first against it tries to stop it, reaches the maximum possible value then immediately changes direction goes in the same direction which it was originally supposed to oppose, and now its not possible to stop it any further so it 'gives up' and you go on your way, this is a more generalized explanation of "static friction is a self adjusting force"
Hope it helps


In this problem, static friction $f$ is working without any initial
$F$ force

That’s not correct. The static friction force $f$ opposes the normal force $N1$ the wall exerts on the ladder. The value of $N1$ is determined by summing the moments about the point of contact with the ground and setting it equal to zero.

I am wondering how static friction works in this case and how limiting
static friction $f_s = \mu_s R$.

In this case $R=W$. If $N1\gt \mu_{s}W$ the maximum possible static friction force would be exceeded and the ladder would slide on the ground.
The answers to the following:
(1) as long as $N1\lt \mu_{s}W$
(2) To the left
(3) it simply tells you what the maximum value of $f$ can be without slipping
For the cyclist, the static frictions force provides the net force acting radially inward (centripetal force) needed for circular motion. It is not “opposing” any external force $F$. In the accelerating frame of the cyclist you can think of it opposing the equal and opposite centrifugal (fictitious) force. The centripetal force is
$$F_{c}=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$
The maximum possible static friction force is
$$f_{max}=\mu_{s}mg$$
For the cyclist to not skid off the circular path
$$ \frac{v^2}{r}\lt \mu_{s}g$$
This limits the cyclist’s maximum speed without sliding.

I get the case for the ladder. What generates the static friction in
this (the cyclist’s) case then?

In essence, static friction is generated to oppose the inertia of the cyclist that that would otherwise keep the cyclist in uniform straight line motion.
In order to initiate circular motion, the cyclist needs to turn the front wheel of the bicycle. If the bicycle were on ice where there’s negligible friction, it would simply continue sliding
in a straight line obeying Newton’s first law. But if the wheel is pushing against a rough surface, friction will act perpendicular to the straight line motion of the wheel causing the centripetal force required to cause circular motion.
Hope this helps.

I see. I get the case for the ladder. Can you explain the case of cyclist? What generates the static friction in this case then?

@akifsami first ask yourself what would happen to the cyclist if there’s no static friction force

And what does the cyclist need to do in order to initiate circular motion?

@akifsami see update to my answer

Got it, thanks man
